# Conflict jquery and contentFlow

Tags: jquery, contentflow

I'm trying to place ContentFlow (http://www.jacksasylum.eu/ContentFlow/) plug-in in a template on google blogger, but I think I have a problem of conflict with jquery.
Basically if I disable jquery it works perfectly but if active jquery, images do not load.
it appreciate some help, thanks.

Comment: Please show your code and what you achieved so far.

Comment: You can try using jQuery.noConflict() to work, but is a weird problem. Are you sure that the libraries are nested in correct order?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow! Please go through posting rules and guidelines. Also instead of answering your question with additional information you can edit the original question.

First off, look into using developer tools for debugging issues like this. You can see what JavaScript error caused your issue, jump to it's code and read the comments in the vicinity and/or google out the root cause.

In my opinion you should search for something fresher than ContentFlow. The issue you're having is due to ContentFlow expecting Prototype.js to be bound to `$`.

[Prototype.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype_JavaScript_Framework) is a jQuery-like library that was popular when jQuery was in it's infancy. Using a plugin that expects it (without stating it in any docs) seems unreasonable. Also there's a lot of bloat from IE6-specific fixes.

If you're determined to use it, then jQuery in [`.noConflict`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/) mode should probably work but I would expect complications down the road.

Alternatively look at [these coverflow jQuery plugins](https://plugins.jquery.com/tag/coverflow/) or any of the [numerous sliders avilable](https://plugins.jquery.com/tag/slider/).